# Grouping duplicate items in a list, and adding their totals

Tags: c#, duplicates

Hello I have a list and I am trying to group duplicates and add their quantity to compare it to a max quantity number. The only problem I'm running into is isolating the duplicates and adding their quantities. I have come to a mental block and just can't figure out the right way to acheive what I am trying. So I was hoping that someone would be able to point me in the right direction and help get me unstuck!

The property that I am checking on for duplicates is the ProductID

```
double qty = 0;
double totalQty = 0;
bool isQtyValid = true;

List<ShoppingCartDTO> shoppingList = ShoppingCart.Fetch(string.Format("WHERE SessionID='{0}'", Session["ID"]));
    foreach (ShoppingCartDTO temp in shoppingList)
    {
        qty =  temp.Quantity;
        totalQty += qty;
        isQtyValid = getCheckQty(totalQty, temp.ProuductID, temp.CustomerID);
        CheckOut.Enabled = isQtyValid;
        lblError.Visible = !isQtyValid;
    }
```

If more explaining can be done, I can try to explain better, as well as provide more code if needed. I appreciate anyone's advice and help. Thanks!

Comment: How are you defining "duplicate"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly:

```
var groupedList = shoppingList.GroupBy( item => item.[the property you want to group by on]);

foreach (var g in groupedList)
{
   var sum = g.Sum( i => i.[the property you want to sum]);
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: did exactly what I was trying to do, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
A.Intersect(B).Count;
```

would this be able to find out the duplicate item count?
You might also implement IEquatable interface for your ShoppingCartDTO class:

```
class ShoppingCartDTO : IEquatable<ShoppingCartDTO>
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Old style solution, something like.

```
List<ShoppingCartDTO> shoppingList = ShoppingCart.Fetch(string.Format("WHERE SessionID='{0}'", Session["ID"]));
    Dictionary<String, Double> groups = new Dictionary<String,Double>();
    foreach (ShoppingCartDTO temp in shoppingList)
    {
        String key = String.Format("{0}-{1}", temp.CustomnerID, temp.ProductID); 
        if (groups.ContainsKey(key))
        {
           groups[key] += temp.Quantity;
        }
        else
        {
           groups.Add(key, temp.Quantity);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's some property that defines your "duplicate" like `ProductId`:

```
var results = shoppingList.GroupBy(s => s.ProductID)
                          .Select(g => new {
                                               ProductID = g.Key,
                                               totalQty = g.Sum(I => i.Quantity)
                                           }
                                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var groups = shoppingList.GroupBy(e => e.ProductId).ToList();
shoppingList.Clear();
foreach (var group in groups)
{
    group.First().Quantity = group.Sum(e => e.Quantity);
    shoppingList.Add(group.First());
}
```

After this runs, `shoppingList` should contain no duplicates and the `Quantity` value will have been summed for all duplicates.